# MongoError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have tree records in mongodb but there could be many more, I'm getting shops by an ID coming from frontend

I need to get 20 records and group them by itemId and colorId, and get counts for every shop. the count of shops can be 1,2,3,....10etc..

this is output I need:

```
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| itemId | colorId  | shop1 | shop2 | shop3 |
+========+==========+=======+=======+=======+
| 1      | colorId1 | 5     | 0     | 3     |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2      | colorId2 | 3     | 0     | 0     |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 3      | colorId2 | 0     | 3     | 0     |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2      | colorId1 | 0     | 5     | 0     |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 3      | colorId1 | 0     | 0     | 5     |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

[here is my data and query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hMROWJZD57s) - here shopId is string and it's work good.

but when I use this query on my local mashine, I'm getting this error:

**MongoError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $arrayToObject requires an object with keys 'k' and 'v', where the value of 'k' must be of type string. Found type: objectId**

but when I change shopId to the ObjectId I'm getting error.
[ObjectId versoin](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hMROWJZD57s)

Comment: Both of your links are with ObjectId and don't currently work. Can I suggest something simpler, like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/11zkWq8KDog ?

Comment: If you have a different result in mind, please write

Comment: hi @nimrod serok, can you please edit your query to be get COUNT in data array and sort it by shopId. please, post your answer. I will vote it! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your request in the comments (if I got it right):

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {}// <-- Highly recommend you to use match due to the complexity of this query
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {
        $push: {
          shopId: "$shopId",
          shopItems: "$shopItems"
        }
      },
      shopIds: {
        "$push": {
          shopId: "$shopId",
          "count": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data.shopItems"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        itemId: "$data.shopItems.itemId",
        colorId: "$data.shopItems.colorId"
      },
      data: {
        $push: {
          shopId: "$data.shopId",
          count: "$data.shopItems.itemCount"
        }
      },
      existing: {
        $push: {
          shopId: "$data.shopId",
          "count": 0
        }
      },
      shopIds: {
        $first: "$shopIds"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "missing": {
        "$setDifference": [
          "$shopIds",
          "$existing"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$data",
          "$missing"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "data.shopId": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      counts: { // here you can change this key
        $push: "$data"
      },
      totalCount: {
        $sum: "$data.count" // if you want it
      }
    }
  }
])
```

After the first `$match`, we `$group` in order to get all shopIds in each document.
Next we `$unwind` and `$group` by the group you wanted: by colorId and itemId. Then we are adding all the shops with count 0 and removing the ones that do have actual count. Last three steps are just for sorting, summing and formating.
You can play with it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vJ62Cbr3Kcq).

Comment: one more question...
how I can use lookup operators to get shopName, productName and color name from another collections? check my link please: https://mongoplayground.net/p/FQNVexkW7R4

Comment: You can do something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/HHt84yNdy49